# Why does Forward List's methods have "after" version, instead of using List's interface?

Tags: c++

`insert`, `emplace`, `erase` and `splice` from `List`, are replaced by `insert_after`, `emplace_after`, `erase_after` and `splice_after` in `Forward List`. Why is that?

*I understand the difference between the methods, I'm asking **why** do we need a different method to do those operations

Comment: I assume you mean 'lists interface', the implementation is quite different

Comment: because lists 'insert' inserts before the provided iterator, whereas forward_lists insert_after inserts after the iterator , it save confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert` is defined as "insert before" for most containers, because `end()` iterator is defined as "one past the end". With `insert()` as "insert before", you can call it on whole range [`begin()`, `end()`], inclusive. If you defined `insert()` as "insert after", calling it on `end()` iterator would be Undefined Behaviour.

This however requires that container supports biderectional iterators, i.e. iterators that can be decremented. `std::forward_list`, to limit memory usage only supports forward iterators. With only forward iterator you cannot go back one element to insert before, so the only available operation is "insert after". It has the limitation that it cannot be called on `end()` iterator, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: That makes sense. But wouldn't it be preferable if Forward List's interface would look the same as List, only in the implementation it would go until *n-1* instead of *n*, and then insert after? Thus doing the same operation as inserting before *n* steps. It sounds like an easier solution

Comment: @Suspicious_1 If `insert()` was O(n) instead of O(1) then you lose the only advantage lists provide. I'm not sure if `insert_after()` is the best solution, but it seems reasonable enough (as long as you consider having `std::forward_list` reasonable, I don't think I've ever seen a use of this structure)